# Proving a given language is not regular

Tags: automata, regular-language

I'm interested in proving the irregularity of some language L, which is defined as follows:

$0, 1 \in L$

If $w \in L$, then $w 1^{|w|} \in L$

I tried to prove this using the pumping lemma, using the string:  $w1^{|N|}$, where $N$ is the constant from the lemma. My initial idea was that if I 'force' $xy$ to either be a part of the first $N$ characters (i.e a substring of $w$) or a part of the last $N$ characters (in which case $xy$ would contain only $1$'s), then by pumping I'd get a string which doesn't belong to the language.
However, the problem is that is that there can be a situation that xy is located exactly at the point of concatenation of $w$ and $1^{|N|}$, at which case its hard to know whether or not pumping leaves us in the language or out of it.

I'd be glad if you could give me some clues as to how to prove this language is irregular.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!!! 
I think I don't understand what you meant. How can we assume w would contain only 0's? I mean, if I understand correctly, it might contain 1. 
Thanks again!

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood how the language was generated. Ignore my last comment

Comment: No problem. Thanks for trying anyway :)

Comment: Okay, I have a different idea: can you prove that if a string $w$ is in the language then we must have $|w| = 2^p$ for some $p \geq 0$? You should be able to do this via induction.

Comment: Thank you! I think I can, using induction. I guess it might help us to prove that Rank(L) is infinite?
Thanks!

Comment: I was still thinking pumping lemma but if you have a different way of going about it then that's fine. I was thinking we could use the restriction on the sizes along with $2^p > p$ to our advantage.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on your idea? I think I don't understand it completely.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Working on an answer now

Comment: Thanks!!! I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any string $w \in L$ we must have either $w = 0, w = 1,$ or $w = w_21^{|w_2|}$ for some other $w_2$ in $L.$ So, we must have that $|w| = 2^x$ for some integer $x \geq 0.$

Here's why: suppose this was not true for every $w \in L.$ Then, there must be some  shortest possible counterexample $s.$ If $s$ is $0$ or $1$ then we trivially have $x = 0.$ If $s$ is anything else, we must have $s = w1^{|w|},$ but because $s$ is a smallest example and clearly $|w| < |s|,$ we must have $|w| = 2^y,$ implying that $|s| = 2^y2^y = 2^{y+1},$ and $y \geq 0$ implies $x = y+1 > 0.$

Now, supposing $L$ had pumping length $p,$ consider the string $1^{2^p} \in L.$ (once again we can prove this is always in $L$ by induction, but I'll spare the details for time's sake)

The pumping lemma tells us that we have to be able to decompose this string as $xyz = 1^{2^p}$ so that $|y| \geq 1, |xy| \leq p,$ and $xy^az \in L$ for all integers $a \geq 0.$ Let's take $a = 2.$

Because $|xy| \leq p$ we can safely say $1 \leq |y| \leq p.$ Now, because $|xy^2z| = |xyz| + |y|,$ adding $2^p$ on all sides gives us $1 + 2^p \leq |xy^2z| \leq p + 2^p.$ Now because $2^p > p$ for all $p \geq 1,$ we can conclude that $2^p < |xy^2z| < 2^p + 2^p = 2^{p+1}.$

Now because $xy^2z$ must be in $L,$ we must have $|xy^2z| = 2^n$ for some integer $n \geq 0,$ giving us $2^p < 2^n < 2^{p+1}.$ Because $f(x) = 2^x$ is strictly increasing, this gives us that $p < n < p+1,$ so $0 < n-p < 1.$ This implies that $n - p$ is not an integer, which contradicts the closure of integers over addition and multiplication.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I really do appreciate it. What a clever solution :)
There's just one little thing - I'd like to make sure I understood this part:
"if s is anything else, we must have s = ${ w 1^{|w|} }$ but because s is the smallest counter example and clearly |s| > |w|, we must have |w| = ${ 2^{y} }$"?
Does this actually means that since s is the smallest counter example, w has to be 0 or 1, which, in particular, means that w is of the form ${ 2^{y} }$?
Thank you!

Comment: $w$ doesn't necessarily have to be $0$ or $1, w$ can actually be any string in the language. An example is $s = 0111, w = 01.$ The point is that because we've defined $s$ as a smallest counterexample, and $w$ is strictly smaller than $s, w$ must follow the rule $|w| = 2^y.$

Comment: This is where I should point out, $s$ is not necessarily *the* smallest counterexample, as that is not necessarily well-defined: there could be multiple smallest counterexamples of the same length. So, we define $s$ as *a* smallest counterexample, such that there are no counterexamples *strictly* shorter than $s.$ Now this is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks! 
I still don't get this part:

I think I don't exactly understand what 'smallest counter-example' means here.
I probably misunderstood something, but it seems to me like in the example you gave, where s = 0111,  s is indeed of the form ${ 2^{x} }$, but we are assuming s is a counter-example, which means we should take s that is not of the form ${ 2^{x} }$.
Where did I go wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Hey sorry, had to step away from the computer for a bit. You’re right that we want to take an s such that $|s| \neq 2^x,$ but remember that we require $s \in L.$  There is no example where both are true, so I gave an example where $s \in L$ as an example of how $s$ and $w$ were related. Sorry if that was confusing

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer and patience! I think I finally got it: since s is the smallest possible counter example that is not of the form${2^{|x|} }$ and since
 |w| < |s|, it must imply that |w| is of the form ${2^{|y|} }$.
Thank you! All the best!

Comment: @stephen-donovan Once you have proved that the lengths of the words of $L$ are powers of two, you don't need the pumping lemma. Just use the fact that regular languages are closed under monoid morphisms and observe that $u \to |u|$ is a morphism.